# Логическое условие для цикла в обработчике событий

Tags: java, button, android-on-click

Есть два массива с картинками,в первом файлы относятся к ответу "да",во втором к "нет",из каждого рандомно вытаскиваем по файлу,перетасовываем и заливаем в фон кнопок,которых всего две,вопрос:как в обработчике нажатия onClick задать условие цикла,"если на кнопке картинка из первого массива,то надпись да,если картинка из второго -нет"? 
П.с. если в кратце,то что то типа:
 int a,d; 
a=R.drawable.image1; 
b=R.drawable.image2; 
Перемешиваем их
И в кнопке
OnClick: 
if(a){условие} else if (b) {условие2}
Каким должно быть логическое выражение для "а" и "b" что бы смогло выполнится условие!
Код:

```
static int [] imageid ={
    R.drawable.ts1, 
    R.drawable.ts2,
    R.drawable.ts3,
    R.drawable.ts4,
    R.drawable.ts5,
    R.drawable.ts6,
}; 

static int [] imageidgr ={
    R.drawable.g1, 
    R.drawable.g2,
    R.drawable.g3,
}; 
    ImageButton bt1,bt2; 
Random generator = new Random();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game); 

    bt1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt1); 
    bt2=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt2);

    ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>(); 
    lista.add(imageid[generator.nextInt(imageid.length)]); 
    lista.add(imageidgr[generator.nextInt(imageidgr.length)]); 

    Collections.shuffle(lista); 

    bt1.setImageResource(lista.get(0)); 
    bt2.setImageResource(lista.get(1));

}

public void v1 (View view){

    if (???){Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                 "Да!",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();}
    else if(???) {Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                       "Нет!",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();}
}
```

Comment: выкладывайте код текстом а не скриншотом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливать в каждой кнопке вместе с изображением тег:

```
bt1.setTag(lista.get(0))
```

И сравнивать при нажатии, какой тег был установлен:

```
if (Arrays.asList(imageid).contains(bt1.getTag())) ...
```

Чтобы изменить изображение на кнопках через 3 сек можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией:

```
final int tmpResource = lista.get(0);
bt1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bt1.setImageResource(tmpResource);
    }
},3000);
```

Comment: asList подчёркивает

Comment: Всё понял,надо добавить List<Integer> ts = Arrays.asList(imageid); спасибо большое за ответ.е сли не очень сложно,можно ещё подсказку:на экране две imagebutton,нажимаем на одну,появляется сообщение "да/нет",а потом нужно допустим через 3секунды сново обновить изображения на этих imagebutton,как это можно реализовать?

Comment: добавил код в ответ

Comment: Сделал в итоге по своему,через рестарт активити,всё равно,спасибо за помощ